# SUMIFS and IndexMatch - dynamic column

Tags: excel

I am new to `IndexMatch` and I've got a `SUMIF` formula that works, but I can't get the `SUMIFS` to work.

I need the column being added to be dynamic based on the value in cell `$C$4`
I only want to add the rows that match a bunch of other criteria.

Here is my `SUMIF`

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!ACCTGRPCOD,Sheet2!A17,INDEX(Sheet1!RawData,0,MATCH(Sheet2!$C$4,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)))
```

Here is my `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!RawData,0,MATCH(Sheet2!$C$4,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)),Sheet1!ACCTGRPCOD,Sheet2!A16,Sheet1!AUDTORG,Sheet2!C1)
```

Help is much appreciated and needed. How do I fix this?

The following `SUMIFS` works, but I want to replace `NETPERD1` with whatever I have in `$C$4`

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!NETPERD1,Sheet1!ACCTGRPCOD,Sheet2!$A17,Sheet1!AUDTORG,Sheet2!C$1,Sheet1!FSCSDSG,Sheet2!C$2,Sheet1!FSCSYR,Sheet2!C$3)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. `INDEX(Sheet1!RawData,0,MATCH(Sheet2!$C$4,Sheet1!$1:$1,0)` makes no sense. Why is the 0? It should be, at least, 1, because it's a row number

Comment: Foxfire and Buns and Burns, So, the row number would be the result(s) of my sumifs conditions.  I need it to add up lots of rows, but only the ones that meet my sumifs conditions.  Maybe I'm using the wrong formula?

Comment: BigBen, I do that all the time with my SUMIFS.  I think my problem is related to what Foxfire And Burns And Burns pointed out.

Comment: Post some sample data from both sheets, as well as where named ranges are located.

Comment: Thank you to all 3 of  you, I'm going to post a new question.  Hopefully I can be more clear.